# How to position content on slideshow for mobile on Impulse theme for Shopify?

Tags: html, css, shopify

I need help with positioning the text and the button on the slideshow for mobile because the slideshow has a different layout on desktop and on mobile version.

I want the slideshow to look like this on mobile

[image]

But right now its looking like this

[image]

This is the custom CSS that I'm using on the Hero (optional slideshow) section

```
    .btn {
  color: #183170 !important;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  padding-right: 3rem;
  font-size: 25px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .animation-contents {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  .btn {
    display: block;
    color: #183170 !important;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.1rem;
    padding-right: 0.1em;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .hero__subtitle {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

Also would like to know how to add a breakpoint on the slideshow text field because the shopify editor doesn't allow to.

In case you need the eshop url is Vitamiracle.com

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this https://prnt.sc/XGCNzi_IsdkT

Comment: Thanks @Onkar do you know how can I cancel that property on the shopify editor?

Comment: Tested what you suggested and it worked Onkar. Thanks for your help.